# Como transformar um método em uma classe?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, winforms

Tenho o seguinte em um formulário:

```
public form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.confirmarFechamento_FormClosing);
}
private void confirmarFechamento_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Você tem certeza que deseja sair?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result != DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Como eu poderia transformar isso em uma classe e apenas chamar como um método?
No caso seria classe `confirmarFechamento` que tem o método `confirmarFechamento`, e no form1 teria o chamamento do método `confirmarFechamento`.

Comment: Qual seria o propósito de fazer isso? Você quer aproveitar o método em mais de um form, é isso?

Comment: Se for isso, você poderia fazer um BaseForm e nele colocar esse evento

Comment: Qual o teu objetivo? utilizar o método em vários locais?

Comment: Sim, eu quero aproveitar o método, usar em várias classes diferentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta clicar com o botão direito no seu projeto, ir em add e depois clicar em class.
Recomendo que dê como nome para a classe um substantivo que represente-a e para o método a ação que ela faz efetivamente. Seu código ficaria assim +/-:

```
public form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.confirmarFechamento_FormClosing);
}


private void confirmarFechamento_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        if (! new Fechamento().ConfirmarFechamento())
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}




public class Fechamento
{
    public bool ConfirmarFechamento()
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Você tem certeza que deseja sair?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        return result == DialogResult.Yes;
    }
}
```

Porém creio que não seria muito útil criar uma classe apenas para isso.

Comment: Uma outra opção seria `Fechamento` e `ConfirmarFechamento` serem estáticos.

Answer (score 0):

Bom você pode criar uma classe para tratar todos seus Forms, assim ficaria mais orientado a objetos, o que facilitaria sua reutilização de código. Assim quando precisar de um metodo que faz alguma ação para seus Forms, seja validar, fechar, cancelar, salvar e etc... Basta referencia-lá e "abusa-lá", rsrs... 
Abraços.

Comment: No caso, como eu poderia fazê-lo?